# Permission being denied as I'm trying to write to a tsv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to write a series of dataframes to a series of seperate tsv files, but I am being met with 'PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied'.

I can't attach an example code, as it is pretty hard to identify where the problem area would be, but I'm fairly certain I do not have the original tsv files open anywhere - the only places the original data files are accessed are in a basic 'read_csv', and if relevant the directories are accessed using os.walk & os.path.

Below is my code for handling output to tsv:

```
for key,value in Collection.items():
    for key1, value1 in value.items():
        foldername = r'C:\Users' + '\\' + key + '\\' + key1 
        if not os.path.isdir(foldername):
            os.makedirs(foldername)
        headerInfo.to_csv(foldername,index=False)
        value1.to_csv(foldername,mode='a',index=False)

        base = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        os.rename(foldername, '.tsv')
```

I'm receiving the error at the lines concerning 'to_csv', so I'm not sure if at any point before that I'm leaving the output file open.

I'd appreciate any insights on my code, but would also like to ask is there another way to bypass the need for permission?

Comment: `foldername` is a directory. You check that with `os.path.isdir(foldername)`. Then you try to write a `csv` to the directory, not a file _in_ the directory, but the directory itself. Hence, the `PermissionError`

Comment: I thought '.to_csv' automatically generated a csv file to the directory location given. Should I explicitly generate a blank csv prior to calling it?

Comment: It will create a csv but you've not given it a name. You're trying to write to something like `C:/folder/`  which is not enough information to define a file output. If you give it `C:/folder/filename.tsv` it will certainly create a new file.

Comment: Is the program running as an admin? If not, why do you expect to have permission to write to multiple different user folders?

Comment: So I've defined a name for the file (essentially foldername + '\\filename.tsv'), changed the 'to_csv' to output to filename, and now I'm getting a 'FileNotFoundError'. I'm generating new file names as the for loop goes on, is that what's leading to this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the foldername in to_csv with a filename (tsvfile below):

```
for key,value in Collection.items():
    for key1, value1 in value.items():
        foldername = r'C:\Users' + '\\' + key + '\\' + key1 
        if not os.path.isdir(foldername):
            os.makedirs(foldername)
        tsvfile = foldername + '\\filename.tsv'
        headerInfo.to_csv(tsvfile, index=False)
        value1.to_csv(tsvfile, mode='a', index=False)
```